# undefined method `...' for nil:NilClass in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am not sure what's wrong with my code here:

```
class ZombieController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @zombies = Zombie.all

    respond_to do |format|
        #format.json {render json: @rotting_zombies}
        format.html
    end

  end
end


class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :name, :rotting, :age
  has_many :tweets
  has_one :brain, dependent: :destroy
  scope :rotting, where(rotting: true)
  scope :fresh, where("age < 30")
  scope :recent,order('created_at desc').limit(3)

end

class Brain < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :flavor, :status, :zombie_id
  belongs_to :zombie
end
```

On Zombie index view I render the zombie name with brain flavour as follows:

```
<h1>List</h1>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td></td>
<td>Flavor</td>
</tr>


<% @zombies.each do |zombie|%>
<tr>
    <td><%= zombie.name %></td>
    <td><%= zombie.brain.flavor %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>




</table>
```

The errors I am receiving are `undefined method`flavor' for nil:NilClass.`
what might be wrong here? As far as I know I correctly defined the relationship both for zombie and brain model.

Comment: Make sure you have proper data in your DB. If you don't have any brain record in your database, the `zombie.brain` will be `nil`. And you will get the error undefined methodflavor' for nil:NilClass.`

Comment: Also, since Zombie has_one Brain, I would have a brain_id in Zombie model rather than zombie_id in Brain model.  What if in database there are multiple Brain records with same Zombie id ? Then one Zombie would have many brains, which is not what you want.

Comment: @unnitallman good points here

Comment: @unnitallman in that case i think we need to use has_many relation using an assignment table

Comment: You also presumably don't want the same brain in many Zombies. ;-) To avoid the current problem, are you ensuring that a Zombie always has a brain when it's created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixing the issue that Rails trying to fetch property from a `nil` object, there are few ways:

### By checking nil in view

change your **views/zombies/index.html.erb**

```
<td><%= zombie.brain.flavor %></td>
```

to

```
<td><%= zombie.brain ? zombie.brain.flavor : "string with no brain here" %></td>
```

### By delegate

In your  **models/zombie.rb**

add `delegate :flavor, :to=>:brain, :prefix=>true, :allow_nil=>true`

And in your **views/zombies/index**, change the line as

```
<td><%= zombie.brain_flavor %></td>
```

### By try()

Thanks @unnitallman

change your **views/zombies/index.html.erb**

```
<td><%= zombie.brain.flavor %></td>
```

to

```
<td><%= zombie.try(:brain).flavor %></td>
```

Comment: same as the above - zombie.brain.try(:flavor) || "Zombie with no brain"